# Shrink an image to fill the remaining space in the page horizontally

Tags: html, css

I have two divs positioned side by side horizontally. The width of the first is determined by the text within it, and I simply want to shrink an image in the second div so that its width fills the remaining horizontal space on the page.

```
+--------------------------------------------+
|           |                                |
|           |                                |
|           |                                |
|           |                                |
|           |                                |
|  <div 1>  |            <div 2>             |
| Some text |          Large image           |
|           |                                |
|           |                                |
|           |                                |
|           |                                |
|           |                                |
+--------------------------------------------+
            <---------remaining-space-------->
<---------------- page width ---------------->
```

Currently, I'm shrinking the image to the page width, but what I really need is to shrink to the page width minus the width of the text div.

I'm after a **CSS** solution with **IE** compatibly and **without hard-coded fixed widths**.

```css
#text
{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  float: left;
}

img
{
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;  
}
```

```html
<div id=text>Some text</div>
<img src="http://www.principiaprogrammatica.com/image.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Can you set img as background?

Comment: No, I can't unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

https://fiddle.jshell.net/qbgnp1ar/2/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="text">Some text</div>
    <div class="image"><img src="http://www.principiaprogrammatica.com/image.jpg"/></div>
</div>

.container {
    width:100%;
}
.image {
    overflow:hidden;
}

.image > img {
  width: 100%
}

.text {
    background:blue;
    float:left;
}
```

And here are some extra info on this: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-block-formatting-contexts-in-css/
a
Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Does that work for you? It's not resizing the image for me. Thanks, I'll read up.

Comment: ops sorry! I updated the fiddle, check now! The selectors I used are just for the example, you can use classes for everything is you wish or any other style you might be using.

Answer (score 1):

You can try **flexbox** and it should work in **IE 11+**

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/363/)**

```css
.content {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.image {
  -webkit-flex: 1; 
  flex: 1;
}

.image img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div id=text>Some text</div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://www.principiaprogrammatica.com/image.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does work in Chrome, although I couldn't verify it works in IE8 because JSFiddle won't work in IE8 ha. In any case, I went with a simpler answer, thanks anyway tho man.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="text">Some text</div>
    <div class="aPicture">
    <img src="http://www.principiaprogrammatica.com/image.jpg"/>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#text
{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  width:15%;
}
.aPicture{
    float:right;
    width:85%;
}
img
{
  max-width: 100%;
  height:auto;  
}
```

Comment: I need <div id=text> to resize dynamically, and for that reason cannot hardcode any widths.

Comment: When the width property is set with % ( percentages ) it automatically becomes dynamically resizable.

Comment: I need it dynamically resizable based upon the width of the text, not a fixed percentage.

Answer (score 0):

set a parent div tag to the image `#div2>img` and then set its `max-width` to `100%`